# Matplotlib in Pyside with Qt designer (PySide)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside

I have been looking for a working example how to embed a matplotlib plot in pyside that is created with the QT designer while keeping the logic in a separate file. I know that there are numerous examples on the web but none of them actually uses the QT designer and then creates a separate file to add the logic where the matplitlib plot is added to a widget. I found an example that 'almost' works http://blog.rcnelson.com/building-a-matplotlib-gui-with-qt-designer-part-1/ but but in my version it's not possible to "Change the layoutName property from “verticalLayout” to “mplvl”".

So I have the following specific questions:
I'm not clear into what item that plot can be embedded to in Pyside Qt designer. Is it a simple "widget" (as there is no matplotlib widget available in pyside). If so, how can I then add the plot to that widget? Or do I have to create a 'FigureCanvas' with Qt Designer? Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Here is the simplest possible design I can make with the Pyside Qt designer in embedding a widget (is this correct?). How can I now add a matplotlib plot on top of it?

As suggested in one of the answers I have now promoted the Qwidget to MyStaticMplCanvas and edited the name of Qwidget to mplvl.

Automatically generated file with Pyside Qt designer and compiled with 
pyside-uic ui.ui -o ui.py -x

ui.py looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Apr 20 14:00:02 2016
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(444, 530)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mplvl = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.centralwidget)
        self.mplvl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 190, 221, 161))
        self.mplvl.setObjectName("mplvl")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 444, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

from mystaticmplcanvas import MyStaticMplCanvas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

how can I now add a plot into the mplvl object from a separate .py file?

Comment: You can not mix `PyQt` and `PySide` imports in the same process.  I suggest you import everything from the `matplotlib.backends.qt_compat` module where we shim over what the differences.

Comment: The code of pyside is automatically generated by pyside-uic so I need to remain somehow. Unless you're saying its not possible?

Comment: I had a similar problem - although there are some differences. Please check out this post on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665850/matplotlib-animation-inside-your-own-pyqt4-gui/36669876#36669876
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not an expert on that matter so it might not be the cleanest way of doing this, but here is some working code to get you started:

- I think the easiest way to add widgets is via a `QxxxxLayout`
- then I just made your `Plotter` inherit from `FigureCanvas`
- and told `matplotlib` to work with `PySide`

ui.py:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(533, 497)
        self.mplvl = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
        self.mplvl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 150, 251, 231))
        self.mplvl.setObjectName("mplvl")
        self.vLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mplvl.setLayout(self.vLayout)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

For this you just have to add the canvas to `mplvl` in `QtDesigner`

main.py:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = 'PySide'
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import random

from weakref import proxy
from ui import Ui_Form


class Plotter(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        self.parent = proxy(parent)
        # random data
        data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]
        fig = Figure()
        super(Plotter,self).__init__(fig)
        # create an axis
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # discards the old graph
        self.axes.hold(False)
        # plot data
        self.axes.plot(data, '*-')

    def binding_plotter_with_ui(self):
        self.parent.vLayout.insertWidget(1, self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    # plotter logic and binding needs to be added here
    plotter = Plotter(ui)
    plotter.binding_plotter_with_ui()
    plotter2 = Plotter(ui)
    plotter2.binding_plotter_with_ui()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now what's left is probably to tweak the `FigureCanvas` to make it the right size and proportions, so you should be able to get what you want looking at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) or [the other](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4_wtoolbar.html).

Good luck!

Comment: To clarify: a widget needs to be put into a layout. In this case the wiedget is named mplvl and the vertical layout vLayout. After that the above code will work.

Comment: The only small problem is that the plot is cut off at the bottom a bit. Is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: What I advise you to do is the following: inside QtDesigner, add a first scroll area where you put a vertical layout (replace ``mplvl``). Then add the plots inside this layout. The size problem on the vertical axis simply comes from your ``self.mplvl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 150, 251, 231))``, which is too small.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the matplotlib example of embedding in QT4: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html

Here they define a couple of classes implementing a matplotlib widget in a QT4 application, e.g. the class `MyStaticMplCanvas`. The trick to use this class inside QT Designer is to use a standard QWidget, right-click it and select `Promote to ...` Fill in the class name `MyStaticMplCanvas` under `Promoted class name`, and the filename where this class is found under `header file` (the extention .h is added, but ignored in the python code). Click `Add` and `Promote`.

Now after compilation by uic the python code should look similar to:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        ...
        self.mplvl = MyStaticMplCanvas(Form)
        ...

from mystaticmplcanvas import MyStaticMplCanvas
```

Comment: That's definitely a step in the right direction. Only problem I have now is that self.setParent(parent) gives an error: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QWidget.setParent(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget'
  QWidget.setParent(QWidget, Qt.WindowFlags): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget'

Comment: Make sure you only import from PySide and nothing from PyQt4. Probably your matplotlib uses PyQt4 by default. The first lines of your script set the correct backend in matplotlib, as in the answer by Silmathoron.

Comment: I have now edited the original question to better show the current status of things