# Adding a label to a Line2D in matplotlib and PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I was experimenting a bit with the answer code of this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61226106/10810208
for my project I am making a live system monitor, but I can't figure out how to put a label on a Line2D, because now it is only 1 line but there will be more.
this is the part I have trouble with:

```py
        self.ax1.set_xlabel('time in 1/10 of a second')
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('usage in %')
        self.line1 = Line2D([], [], color='blue') #here I need to add the label to
        self.line1_tail = Line2D([], [], color='blue', linewidth=2)
        self.line1_head = Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='o', markeredgecolor='r')
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1)
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1_tail)
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1_head)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, self.xlim)
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

I just cant figure out why adding: `Line2D([],[], color='blue', label='cpu')` doesn't work. Am I just stupid right now?

here is the full code:

```py
###################################################################
#                                                                 #
#                    PLOT A LIVE GRAPH (PyQt5)                    #
#                  -----------------------------                  #
#            EMBED A MATPLOTLIB ANIMATION INSIDE YOUR             #
#            OWN GUI!                                             #
#                                                                 #
###################################################################

import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import functools
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.animation import TimedAnimation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import time
import threading
import subprocess
import platform
from os import linesep

import psutil




class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        # Define the geometry of the main window
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("my first window")
        # Create FRAME_A
        self.FRAME_A = QFrame(self)
        self.FRAME_A.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % QColor(210,210,235,255).name())
        self.LAYOUT_A = QGridLayout()
        self.FRAME_A.setLayout(self.LAYOUT_A)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FRAME_A)

        # Place the matplotlib figure
        self.myFig = CustomFigCanvas()
        self.LAYOUT_A.addWidget(self.myFig, *(0,1))
        # Add the callbackfunc to ..
        myDataLoop = threading.Thread(name = 'myDataLoop', target = dataSendLoop, daemon = True, args = (self.addData_callbackFunc,))
        myDataLoop.start()
        self.show()
        return

  

    def addData_callbackFunc(self, value):
        # print("Add data: " + str(value))
        self.myFig.addData(value)
        return

''' End Class '''


class CustomFigCanvas(FigureCanvas, TimedAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        self.addedData = []
        print(matplotlib.__version__)
        # The data
        self.xlim = 200
        self.n = np.linspace(0, self.xlim - 1, self.xlim)
        a = []
        b = []
        a.append(2.0)
        a.append(4.0)
        a.append(2.0)
        b.append(4.0)
        b.append(3.0)
        b.append(4.0)
        self.y = (self.n * 0.0) + 50
        # The window
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        # self.ax1 settings
        self.ax1.set_xlabel('time in 1/10 of a second')
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('usage in %')
        self.line1 = Line2D([], [], color='blue')
        self.line1_tail = Line2D([], [], color='blue', linewidth=2)
        self.line1_head = Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='o', markeredgecolor='r')
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1)
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1_tail)
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1_head)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, self.xlim)
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        TimedAnimation.__init__(self, self.fig, interval = 50, blit = True)
        return

    def new_frame_seq(self):
        return iter(range(self.n.size))

    def _init_draw(self):
        lines = [self.line1, self.line1_tail, self.line1_head]
        for l in lines:
            l.set_data([], [])
        return

    def addData(self, value):
        self.addedData.append(value)
        return

    def zoomIn(self, value):
        bottom = self.ax1.get_ylim()[0]
        top = self.ax1.get_ylim()[1]
        bottom += value
        top -= value
        self.ax1.set_ylim(bottom,top)
        self.draw()
        return

    def _step(self, *args):
        # Extends the _step() method for the TimedAnimation class.
        try:
            TimedAnimation._step(self, *args)
        except Exception as e:
            self.abc += 1
            print(str(self.abc))
            TimedAnimation._stop(self)
            pass
        return

    def _draw_frame(self, framedata):
        margin = 2
        while(len(self.addedData) > 0):
            self.y = np.roll(self.y, -1)
            self.y[-1] = self.addedData[0]
            del(self.addedData[0])

        self.line1.set_data(self.n[ 0 : self.n.size - margin ], self.y[ 0 : self.n.size - margin ])
        self.line1_tail.set_data(np.append(self.n[-10:-1 - margin], self.n[-1 - margin]), np.append(self.y[-10:-1 - margin], self.y[-1 - margin]))
        self.line1_head.set_data(self.n[-1 - margin], self.y[-1 - margin])
        self._drawn_artists = [self.line1, self.line1_tail, self.line1_head]
        return

''' End Class '''


# You need to setup a signal slot mechanism, to
# send data to your GUI in a thread-safe way.
# Believe me, if you don't do this right, things
# go very very wrong..
class Communicate(QObject):
    data_signal = pyqtSignal(float)

''' End Class '''



def dataSendLoop(addData_callbackFunc):
    # Setup the signal-slot mechanism.
    mySrc = Communicate()
    mySrc.data_signal.connect(addData_callbackFunc)

    # Simulate some data
    n = np.linspace(0, 499, 500)
    y = 50 + 25*(np.sin(n / 8.3)) + 10*(np.sin(n / 7.5)) - 5*(np.sin(n / 1.5))
    i = 0

    while(True):
        if(i > 499):
            i = 0
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
        #mySrc.data_signal.emit(y[i]) # <- Here you emit a signal!
        mySrc.data_signal.emit(psutil.cpu_percent())
        i += 1
    ###
###

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: after adding a label to a line object, you also then need to add a legend to the Axes instance. See, for example, here: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

Comment: What do you mean by "putting a label on a Line2D"? To [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html) it? The keyword `label=` is used when generating the legend and works as expected. Edit: Ah, tmdavison is probably right - I don't see that you actually generate the legend.

Comment: @tmdavison thanks, that works. Was just stupid.